# Backbone with SEO Server - Making them work together

Tags: backbone.js, seo

I have been researching like crazy trying to find a way to make my backbone application seo friendly.  Ideally, I would like to use https://github.com/thomasdavis/seoserver which should be a no hassle setup, but there is a problem.

All of these solutions use a rewrite rule requiring a hashed url:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^escaped_fragment=(.)$ 
RewriteRule (.) http://address-of-seoserver:3000/%1? [P]
```

And I'm using HTML5 Push State URL in my backbone app. Is there some way to tell google to redirect only the application pages without a hashed url?

Answer (score 0):

First since you won't have a hash you will have to tell google that you are trying to load ajax content.
Make sure the following is in your head tag for all of the pages that won't have a hash

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

You can then use the follow rewrite rule for google bots.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}:3000%{REQUEST_URI}? [P]
```